# XML parsing on new thread

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsthread, nsoperation

In my application, I want to fetch new xml data after user scrolls through tableview and pulls the first cell down. As the data is loaded in tableview in chronological order, the updated data will be shown before the first cell.

I want to run this process on new thread, so what is the best option :

1. Subclass NSThread and use its instance
2. Subclass NSOperation and use its instance
3. Use NSThread methods directly

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass NSOperation, it's much more convenient than NSThread.

Take a look at this post which help me a lot : 
http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/